# Composite Key in BerkeleyDB cs

Tags: c#, key, composite, berkeley-db

I want to build a B-tree file using the BerkeleyDB application, my key is composed of three fields which contained in a structure:

```
struct Key
{
    int PC;
    DateTime D;
    int Path;
}
```

The question is how to create such composite key by using csharp programming in BerkeleyDB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use c#, but you will have to make one key out of the three yourself. Just write out the entire structure as a fixed length key.

Comment: in this case , how to merge the int and  datetime to get one key?

Comment: If it were C++ you would write out the entire structure as a sequence of bytes. It will be a fixed size so its easy. The int gets written out first, then immediately after that, the DateTime, then, after that, the last int.